# Trying to detect child views in the onTouchEvent in a custom view

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, gesture

I'm trying to make a game for kids, in this game you have figures made with some stars, the kid must connect the stars using the finger. I've everything done except for one thing,  when the finger comes through one of the stars, the star must turn red and make a noise.

[image]

The star does turn red a make a noise, but only if I make tap on them. If I try to drag the finger through the figure, only the first star where I did tap will ring and turn red, the rest will not. My custom view is a class that extends from `RelativeLayout` wich have some `ImageView`'s in there, that are the stars. To add the stars I just read the data about the figure from a data structure and I instantiate the `ImageView`'s on the fly, adding them the proper margin to make the figure. So far I've tried use the `setOnTouchListener` in each star, override the `onTouchEvent` from the stars views, use the `setOnTouchListener`, `onTouchEvent`, `setOnHoverListener` and `setOnDragListener` in the `RelativeLayout`. In each of this methods the way that I've implemented to check the views in the callback is by doing:

```
            for (View v : vStarsCollection) {
                Rect viewBounds = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
                if (viewBounds.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.right_simon_sound);
                    mp.start();
                    ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.star_red);
                }
            }
```

Where `vStarsCollection` is a collection of the `ImageView` that I added in the `RelativeLayout`. Like I told you, the code works when I do tap, but doesnt when I drag the finger across the stars. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the touch listener to each star, try adding to your custom view (i.e., relativelayout).

Then in the onTouch callback, add your existing logic to change the color.

So that onTouch will not go out of your view bounds

Comment: Sorry but that I've already done it, I wrote It in the question  "...So far I've tried use the setOnTouchListener in each star, override the onTouchEvent from the stars views, use the setOnTouchListener, onTouchEvent, setOnHoverListener and setOnDragListener in the RelativeLayout." The `RelativeLayout` that I'm speaking is the custom view.